# tkinter new class can't use .get()/float()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have defined a new `Entry` subclass: `NewEntry`, but it can't get the numbers which are put in it. How can I fix this?

When I click the button, the error message is showed:

> ```
> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> ```

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()                                                                                                                              

class NewEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self,parent,cusdef='1'):      #Initiation default number is '1'                                      
        Entry.__init__(self,parent)
        self.cusdef = cusdef
        v=StringVar()
        v.set(self.cusdef)
        self = Entry(self,textvariable=v)
        self.pack()
        return

def GetNum():
    a=e.get()
    print float(a)
    return

e = NewEntry(root)
e.pack(fill='x')

button = Button(root,command=GetNum)
button.pack(fill='x')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The indenting on your code sample seems to have been messed up. Also what output do you get when you put it through a debugger? Does that exception come with a stack trace that shows the line number where the error came from?

Comment: I never imaged I can get reply so quickly. It's my first time use "class defintion" in python. Maybe I can learn more from python documentation and your help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to initialize your `Entry` subclass here:

```
self = Entry(self,textvariable=v)
self.pack()
```

But instead, you're merely overwriting the variable called `self` and creating a new `Entry` which gets discarded.

Instead you need to do the `Entry.__init__` call once, with the correct arguments:

```
class NewEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self,parent,cusdef='1'):
        self.cusdef = cusdef
        v=StringVar()
        v.set(self.cusdef)
        Entry.__init__(self,parent, textvariable=v)
        self.pack()
        return
```